# Bootstrap active Nav-Tab resets to first after javascript button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a weird issue with Bootstrap Nav-tabs.

I put this button in the third tab that calls a JavaScript simple function that fills up a textarea within the same third tab

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-s" onclick="seoRandom()">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
```

When I click that button, the function works fine but Nav-tab jumps to the first tab.

Any clue to prevent this?

Comment: Please show us the javascript code, and html tabs code too

Comment: I finally found the solution adding onclick="seoRandom(); return false;". Thank you.